# How to display loading spinner in a textbox on clicking of a button?

Tags: jquery, spinner, loading

How to display loading spinner in a textbox on clicking of a button?
Say I have a username and password textbox, and a login button. Once i enter username and password and clicking on Login button, the spinners should be displayed in the textboxes. Kindly help. Iam looking for a JQuery option or Javascript.

Comment: Just position a couple of animated gifs over the textboxes and  use jQuery to toggle their visibility

Comment: i think this can not be done ..... but you can go with some alternate ways like create div and on button's lick show this div on the place of textbox with such type of luck and feel that it will be visible like textbox.

Comment: You need to show spinners inside a textbox?? Or parallel to the textboxes?

Comment: Need to show spinners inside the textbox, or even next to textbox would be fine.

Answer (score 51):

Let's say your html has following textbox :

```
<input id='inputsource' />
```

Define a new css class

```
.loadinggif 
{
   background:
     url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif')
     no-repeat
     right center;
}
```

and then adding this class to your testbox by jquery code:

```
$('#inputsource').addClass('loadinggif');
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/FAVN5/

Comment: Thanks for a simple visual solution to dynamic form updating ;-)

Comment: How can we set height and width of that image?

Comment: here background-size: 20px; //for all sides

Comment: Please note the jsfiddle.net sample's spinner image does not exist anymore. So the sample will not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "spinner" image as a background image to your inputs when submitting the form :

CSS:

```
input.spinner {
    background-image:url('spinner.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 5px /* Change to accommodate to your spinner */
}
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $f = $(this);
    $f.submit(); /* replace with your ajax call */
    $f.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')
        .val('') /* Remove values or store them if you need them back */
        .addClass("spinner") /* Add the spinning image */
        .attr("disabled", "disabled"); /* Disable the inputs */
});
```